# Using Cache in UserViewSet in djoser in django / djangorestframework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, djoser

i am currently using cache_page from decorators in django rest framework to cache the api.

For authentication I am using djoser with django rest framework, but i dont understand how i  can add cache_page decorator in djoser urls.

This is my one of the viewset for cache

```
class TagViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=Tags.objects.all()
    serializer_class=TagSerializer
    permission_classes=[permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes= [authentication.TokenAuthentication]

    #Cache

    @method_decorator(cache_page(30))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
       return super(TagViewSet, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

i want exactly the same with djoser urls but i dont have the userviewset and i dont know how to access it.

views.py (user)

```
empty
```

Please guide me how i can add cache_page for djoser urls

**UPDATE**

added urls.py of djoser

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import *



app_name='users'



urlpatterns = [
    
    path('api/auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('api/auth/', include('djoser.urls.authtoken')),
    
]
```

Comment: Can you share your `urls.py` where you are assigning the url to djoser ?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi Yes i have updated with ```urls.py``` of djoser

Comment: If you have direct urls then you can use `path('api/auth/', cache_page(300)(DjoserApiAuthClass.as_view()), name='api_auth')`. But since this is a whole file of urls.py you have to manually copy all urls from that djoser.urls and paste it in your currenty urls.py with cache_page.

Comment: @DeepakTripathi I understand, so i have to add cache_page for every url separately?